# Percentage based problems::::

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A shopkeeper every once in a while raises his price by a% and then
>   while reduces all the new prices by a%. After one such up down cycle,
>   the price of an article goes down by rs 441. After a second down up
>   cycle, the article was sold for rs 1944.81. What was the original
>   price of the article?

How to approach this question to solve the answer, if I take price as 100, then again a percentage process, the price is reduced by 441 and second up down cycle 1944.81.

**Please anyone guide me answer for this question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When he raises the price and then reduces it, the price is multiplied by $(1+\frac a{100})(1-\frac a{100})=1-\frac {a^2}{10000}$  You have two sentences that each give you one equation.  If the original price is $p$, what is the reduction in the first cycle?  What is the final price?  Two equations, two unknowns.

If you want to guess and check, the fact that $441=21^2$ is a hint.

Comment: I am not able to get you?@Ross millikan, share the steps and answer please

Comment: As I said, if the original price is $p$, the price after the first cycle is $p(1-\frac {a^2}{10000})$.  You are given that this is $441$ less than $p$.  Write that equation.  Now multiply again to get the price after the second cycle.  Set that equal to ???.  That is your second equation.

Comment: Try it with small numbers.  Start with a price of $100$, increase it $10\%$, decrease that $10\%$.  What do you get?  How does that match with what I have written?  Do you know what it means to increase a price by $a\%$?

Comment: ok Now i have understood Thank you so Much please upvote my question@RossMillikan, if you like it